# Define specific spark executors per worker on a Spark cluster of 3 worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, executor, apache-spark-standalone, cluster-manager

I have a Spark cluster of 3 servers (`1 worker per server = 3 workers`). The resources are very much the same across servers (`70 cores, 386GB of RAM each`).

I also have an application that I `spark-submit`, with `120 cores` and `200GB ram` (24 executors).

When I submit the aforementioned app, my cluster manager (standalone) assign all executors to the first two workers and leave the third worker alone without any executor being occupied there.

I want to assign a specific number of executors at each worker and not let the cluster manager (yarn, mesos, or standalone) decide, as with this setup the load of the 2 workers (servers) is extremely high, leading to disk utilization 100%, disk I/O issues, etc.

- Spark version: 2.4.4
- Cluster Manager: Standalone (Will yarn solve my issue?)

I searched everywhere without any luck.

Comment: can you post some info from the Spark UI? The math seems confusing: 3 servers, 70 cores, 24 executors, 120 cores, ...). Can't really make out what's the hardware and config. Also post the commands you use to bring up your cluster and the `spark.conf` if you have your own.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Please share if you have solved this issue.